# A list of size two not accepting index of 0 Python IndexError

Tags: python

I'd like to apologize if this question is too obvious or been asked before, but I've been stuck on this problem for several hours.

I'm creating a program that takes a list of information about a customer and adjusts their balance based on a separate file that is composed of a list of two values. The First value of each list is an identification number that will be compared and then adjusts the other value of the list.

I get the: `IndexError: list index out of range` for the line `if i[0] == y[0]:`

```
def computeTransactions(transactions, old_master_list):
   transaction_list = []
   for y in old_master_list:
      for line in transactions:
         b = line.split()
         print b
         transaction_list.append(b)
      print transaction_list         
      for i in transaction_list:
        print len(i)
        if i[0] == y[0]:
            y[2] = float(y[2])
            i[1] = float(i[1])
            y[2] += i[1]
            y[2] = round(y[2], 2)
            y[2] = str(y[2])
      print ""
      print y
```

I would really appreciate any help you could provide. Thanks!

EDIT:
I'd like to thank everyone who took the time to help me, I found the answer. It turns out that the "transactions" (which was a file that I opened) was appending a blank space at the end, so I had an extra empty list at the end of the `transaction_list`. A simple `transaction_list = filter(None, transaction_list)` actually solved my problem. I'm sorry if this then was a waste of time

Comment: What do you see when you do `print len(y)` alongside the `print len(i)`?

Comment: Just before `if i[0] == y[0]:` write `print y` and see what value it is having? It must be empty.

Comment: It's not clear what type of data i or y are. Typically, those are ints used as indexes in a list, but you seem to be using them as lists... So you are iterating a list of lists? That being said, it would be useful to see what the parameters of transactions and old master list are

Comment: or better yet just print i and y  ...

Comment: i and y are both lists. "transaction_list" is a two-dimensional list that I am iterating through with i. I previously tried to access the same item using `transaction_list[0][0] == y[0]` which TECHNICALLY worked but it obviously only accessed one of the indexes. the problem came when introducing a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're consuming `transactions` multiple times when you should only be consuming it once:

```
def computeTransactions(transactions, old_master_list):
    transaction_list = []

    for line in transactions:
        b = line.split()
        transaction_list.append(b)

    for y in old_master_list:
        for i in transaction_list:
            if i[0] == y[0]:
                y[2] = float(y[2])
                i[1] = float(i[1])
                y[2] += i[1]
                y[2] = round(y[2], 2)
                y[2] = str(y[2])
```